# Git revert pull doesn't work

Tags: git, git-pull, git-reset, git-revert

I did a mistake this morning and pull my master on my branch.

[image]

I try reset to HEAD@{13} but doesn't work, my work is still missing :s

Thanks for your futur help,

Comment: Can you check out `f8837a5`? And was that pull a fast-forward (like it seems to say)? Then there cannot be anything lost really. Did you commit all your work at one point?

Comment: How did you reset? i.e. did you do a hard or soft reset?

Comment: Okay thanks, i doesn't know we can checkout on f8837a5 (here i use 1dce04e...) i finally found my code. And melak it was an hard reset.